# Change placeholder text input form

Tags: php, input, woocommerce

I am trying to change the placeholder text of my input for the searchform.

```
    <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Waar ben je naar op zoek?', 'placeholder', 'fancy-lab' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
```

The string **'Waar ben je naar op zoek?'** needs to be changed to something more personal when the user is logged in. We already are adding these changes to other parts of the site and I am using this code for other parts:

```
<?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
        echo $current_user->user_login; 
    }
    ?>
```

When I've added this I am getting multiple errors, the first one is due to the global part. So when changing the code to this:

```
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( global $current_user; wp_get_current_user();
                                if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
                                    echo $current_user->user_login; 
                                }
                                , 'placeholder', 'fancy-lab' ); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
```

I am getting the error: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL)

Can anyone help me? Trying to understand the syntax correctly!

Comment: _"I am getting multiple errors"_ - Please share all errors (and the code that causes them, with their context). It's hard to help if we don't know what we're helping with.

Comment: I understand, updated the original question with the code and error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you functions.php create 1 method which will return logged user username or string  and use this in the placeholder:

```
function searchFormPlaceholder(){
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        echo $current_user->display_name;
    } else {
        echo 'Not logged';
    }
}
```

And then inside placeholder tag you call your function:

```
<input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php searchFormPlaceholder(); ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" />
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked!